# Can't get my browser to show me the mobile version of my website

Tags: mobile, user-agent

I'm trying to debug something in the mobile version of my website, but I just can't make it show up on my desktop browser. I'm using the plugin "User Agent Switcher" on Firefox with this user agent:

Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:35.0) Gecko/35.0 Firefox/35.0

Even so, I still see the desktop version of my website:

http://www.axonnsays.com

The mobile version of my website should not show the sidebar (no categories, no search, no tag cloud) and the menu should only be showable via a button somewhere on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your site is responsive so just reduce the size of your browser and reload. You should see the responsive behavior based on your browser size.

This is what I saw when I viewed your site by changing the browser size. It didn't show the sidebar and menu is via burger button as you mentioned. However, the banner image is overlapping the text which you need to fix.

[image]

Comment: Haha. I actually DID reduce the size of my browser's window so that I could test the mobile-only CSS I added. But I should have reduced it even more, which I didn't. And by the way, that's exactly what I'm trying to fix :D. In my mobile CSS I added a "padding-bottom:60px;" but for some reason the div won't listen to it, which is why I'm trying to see my website on desktop, so that I can try to figure out why the padding is not applied. LATER EDIT: I just noticed that my website already has a different CSS for mobile :). Didn't see that before. It's a new theme :).

Comment: Rather than resizing the browser manually Chrome has this feature bit in... simply right click on the page, inspect element then the mobile icon (second icon from the left) then click the 'Device' pull down, this will allow you to click the device you want to view the page on, i.e iphone, you could also test the speed by clicking the drop down throttle to G2, G3, G4 etc... Resizing browser window is a good and quick method, but shouldn't be considered a reliable way of testing a website.

Comment: Yes, chrome developer tools is the best way to go about it if you are debugging the CSS.